# How to upload,display,download and delete files using spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi am trying to do operations like uploading a file,displaying a file,downloading a file and deleting a file using spring mvc i got success in uploading file and deleting file all operations working fine but then whats happening is when i do uploading the uploaded file or image displaying or downloading twice and getting 
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response**

```html
    <form method="post" action="doUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <table border="0">
           <tr>
               <td>Pick file #1:</td>
                <td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" /></td>
             </tr>
       <tr>
                        <td>Pick file #2:</td>
                        <td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

<table border="1" bgcolor="black" width="600px">
<tr style="background-color: teal; color: white; text-align: center;"
        height="40px">
<td>File Name</td>
<td>Image</td>
<td>Download</td>
<td>Delete</td>
</tr>
    <c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="user">
      <tr style="background-color: white; color: black; text-align: center;"
                                                height="30px">
            <td><c:out value="${user.fileName}" /></td>
            <td><img src="show?id=${user.id}" /></td>
            <td><a href="edit?id=${user.id}">Download</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete?id=${user.id}">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

```
    @Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RegistrationController {
    @Autowired
    private IRegistrationService registerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveParentAndStudentFromAdmin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveParentAndStudentByAdmin(
            @ModelAttribute Student student,
            @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) {
        if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
            for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload) {
                System.out.println("Saving file: "
                        + aFile.getOriginalFilename());
                student.setFileName(aFile.getOriginalFilename());
                student.setFileType(aFile.getContentType());
                student.setData(aFile.getBytes());
                registerService.saveParentAndStudentByAdmin(student);
            }
        }
        java.util.List<Student> uploadedFiles = registerService.findAllFiles();
        return new ModelAndView("StudentEnrollmentFromAdmin", "employeeList",
                uploadedFiles);

    }

    @RequestMapping("delete")
    public ModelAndView deleteUser(@RequestParam int id) {
        registerService.deleteRow(id);
        java.util.List<Student> uploadedFiles = registerService.findAllFiles();
        return new ModelAndView("StudentEnrollmentFromAdmin", "employeeList",
                uploadedFiles);

    }

    @RequestMapping("show")
    public ModelAndView displayImage(@RequestParam int id,
            HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println("Id to display image: " + id);
        Student item = registerService.get(id);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
        try {
            response.getOutputStream().write(item.getData());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            response.getOutputStream().close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("StudentEnrollmentFromAdmin");
    }

    @RequestMapping("downalod")
    public ModelAndView downloadFile(@RequestParam int id,
            HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println("Id to download: " + id);

        Student student = registerService.get(id);
        response.setContentType(student.getFileType());
        response.setContentLength(student.getData().length);
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                + student.getFileName() + "\"");

        try {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(student.getData(), response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.util.List<Student> uploadedFiles = registerService.findAllFiles();
        return new ModelAndView("StudentEnrollmentFromAdmin", "employeeList",
                uploadedFiles);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question you may do something like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@PathVariable("idForm") String idForm)
{
    try
    {
        Student item = registerService.get(id);
        HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        //Change it with your real content type
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("img","jpg");
        respHeaders.setContentType(mediaType);
        respHeaders.setContentLength(file.length());
        //I suppose you have a method "getFileName"
                //By using attachment you download the file; by using inline you should see the image in the browser
        respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", item.getFileName());
        InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new ByteArrayOutputStream(item.getData()));
        return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String message = "Error; "+e.getMessage();
        logger.error(message, e);
        return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Angelo

Comment: see i have updated my question after tried some more things

Comment: You can't return a new ModelAndView if you use the response outputstream; o you return null o you use the code i posted